# Proving right cosets are equal or disjoint

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let G be a group, H is a subgroup of G.  Let $Hx = \{hx | h\in H\}$.  Show that given $a, b \in G$, then $Ha \cap Hb = \emptyset$ or $Ha=Hb$.

Suppose we have a $y \in Ha$.  This means that $y=ha$ for some $h \in H$.  Now we have two cases.
Suppose a=b.  Then $y=ha=hb$.  Since $hb \in Hb$, $y \in Hb$.  Thus, $Ha\subseteq Hb$ and $Hb\subseteq Ha$
Now suppose $a\neq b$, then I know from a lemma in the textbook that $ha\neq hb$.  Thus, $Ha \nsubseteq Hb$.  Thus, $Hb \nsubseteq Ha$.  Thus,  $Ha \cap Hb = \emptyset$

Comment: if $a=b$ then obviously $Ha=Hb$ you don't even need to explain this. if $a\not = b$ then $ha\not =hb$ i agree, but it doesn't mean that $Ha\not\subseteq Hb$

Comment: here is a hint: first prove that $Ha=Hb$ if and only if $ab^{-1}$ is an element of $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $ha\neq hb$ does not imply $Ha\not\subseteq Hb$, it might just be that for all $h\in H$, there is $h'\neq h$ in $H$ such that $ha = h'b$.
2. $Ha\not\subseteq Hb$ and $Hb\not\subseteq Ha$ does not imply $Ha\cap Hb =\emptyset$.

*(Ok, to be fair, it does if you already know what you want to prove, but that would be circular argument. But, what I mean is $\{0,1\}\not\subseteq \{1,2\}$ and $\{1,2\}\not\subseteq \{0,1\}$, but $\{0,1\}\cap\{1,2\} \neq \emptyset.$)*

3. Premise that $a\neq b$ will lead to $Ha\cap Hb = \emptyset$ is wrong. If $b = ha$ for $e\neq h\in H$, then $Hb = Hha = Ha$. Notice that I've used another counterexample in the previous one: $e\neq h\in H$, but $He = H = Hh$.

**Hint:** $a\sim b$ iff $ab^{-1}\in H$ is equivalence relation where equivalence class of $a$ is right coset $Ha$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose

$k \in Ha \cap Hb; \tag 1$

then there must exist $h_1, h_2 \in H$ with

$k = h_1a; \; k = h_2b; \tag 2$

thus

$h_1a = h_2b, \tag 3$

whence

$a = h_1^{-1}h_2b, \tag 4$

which clearly implies

$a \in Hb, \tag 5$

and so

$Ha \subset Hb; \tag 6$

interchanging he roles of $a$ and $b$, we see that

$Hb \subset Ha, \tag 7$

so

$Ha = Hb. \tag 8$

We have shown that if $Ha$ and $Hb$ have at least one element in common, then they are the same.  Therefore

$Ha \cap Hb \ne \emptyset \Longrightarrow Ha = Hb; \tag 9$

and by contraposition,

$Ha \ne Hb \Longrightarrow Ha \cap Hb = \emptyset. \tag{10}$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong. Firstly, as noted by yanko in comments, if $a=b$ then of course $Ha=Hb$. Your mistake is: $ha\neq hb\implies Ha\not\subseteq Hb$. I give you a somehow trivial counterexample: take $h,h'\in H$ such that $h\neq h'$. You can prove that $Hh=Hh'=H$.

To prove your assertion, note that you have $G=\bigcup_{x\in G}Hx$. What you're asked to prove is simply that $\{Hx\mid x\in G\}$ is a partition of $G$, so you can think of the $Hx$ as equivalence classes of the equivalence relation:

$$\forall x,y\in H,\,x\sim y\iff xy^{-1}\in H.$$

So, prove that this is an equivalence relation and that the class of $x$ is $Hx$.